# Ionic: I could open my emulator but couldn't launch my app on it

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

When I run 'ionic cordova run android', my emulator opens up but not my app project. And there is error saying exited with code 1.

I have already set my ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME.

Please help.

Below is what I get:

No hardare devices found, attempting emulator...
Error: Command failed: C:\Users\LLH\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop

```
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
```

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.

```
    native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-d... exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Here is my ionic info:

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI          : 5.1.0 (C:\Users\LLH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2
```

Cordova:

```
   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0, (and 6 other plugins)
```

Utility:

```
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.6
```

System:

```
   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\LLH\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: run code with --verbose

Comment: update your platform tools to 29.0.1

Comment: Yes I did an I manage to open the app on emulator already!
Thanks for your help!!